# I want to insert form multiple data in database in one column with single primary key

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert multiple data into table in single column with same primary key when form is submitting using php sql.

Here is the filled form -

[image: form with data]

I want to insert into table using php & sql (ajax if need) like this below link-

[image: [table with data i hope]

Comment: Sure, what was your try to do what you want? and what is the problem?

Comment: Can you put some code here?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please improve your question showing your own attempt as code in text form. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54667445/edit) link below your question. See also [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Split it into 2 table. Don't use one table

Comment: See also [n:m relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990459/how-to-create-tables-with-nm-relationship-in-mysql) Basically you have master data like items and customers. Then you have flow data like orders, stock aso., expressing relations between the master data and adding data like date, quantity aso.

Comment: Thanks for giving advices to me. i only need to get the logic. i got the point with splitting 2 table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same isssue while making API for PHP.

Try this , declare your Item name , quanity and date as TEXT and insert nested JSON in those fields.

i.e.

```js
//while adding to DB json will look like

"[{ABC},{PQR},{XYZ}]","[{23},{56},{14}]","[{23/05/1900 12:00 GMT},{23/05/1908 12:00 GMT},{23/05/1980 12:00 GMT}]"
```

So,

`"[{ABC},{PQR},{XYZ}]"` go to item_name column,

`"[{23},{56},{14}]"` goes to quantity column,

`"[{23/05/1900 12:00 GMT},{23/05/1908 12:00 GMT},{23/05/1980 12:00 GMT}]"` goes to date column

as simple string or text. Here's below is my HTML Code for Table (Ignore style ☺)

```html
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>ITEM_NAME</td>
    <td>QUANTITY</td>
    <td>DATE</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>ABC</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>23/05/1900 12:00 GMT</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>PQR</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>23/05/1908 12:00 GMT</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>XYZ</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>23/05/1980 12:00 GMT</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

So while adding to Database you need first push data to object then **Stringyfy** it and then send to database.
And while fetching from database and displaying again to UI , you need to **Parse** those strings back to Objects then you can apply looping like it is an Nested object.

Happy Codeing ☻

Answer (score 1):

You can not use multiple rows with same primary key..For every Item you have to create separate row.

If you want to implement these then there are 2 way:

1) create Main Table: which contain all row info other than item info.
   Create sub table : which contain all item info by using main_table_id as forgin key.

2) You can create item column & store all item & quantity into in JSON format.(mysql>=5.7 support json format) like :

```
id    Item_data (json format)                                        date
1     {["name":"Pen","quantity":10],["name":"xyz","quantity":1]}     2019/02/13
2     {["name":"gfdgf","quantity":10],["name":"asa","quantity":1]}   2019/02/13
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this the one way and split in to 2 table the other way. thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options in your situation:

1. Serialize data (see the answer below). Notice that it's almost impossible to run queries on this data.
2. Use an extra table for your items. Then use a foreign key that connect this item to your main table
3. Use a no-sql database (for example MongoDB). In no-sql databases it is possible to store complete "objects" (called documents) with multiple child-objects