# Conditional Column on sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a new table on my DB, the table has 2 important columns

id_brands (This is an FK from the table *brands*)
id_veiculo

What I would like to have is something like this:

| id_brands | id_veiculo |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |

I create the table but I'm trying to find a way to make this condition with a trigger but without success, I don't know if it's possible or if a trigger is the best way to do that.

Comment: What condition? And why would a trigger be involved? What you posted is a many-to-many table combining Brands and Vehicles. It probably makes sense to delete rows automatically if a Brand or Vehicle is deleted (although business software rarely deletes rows) and that can be done using CASCADE DELETE foreign key constraints or triggers on the Brands and Vehicles tables. If you wanted to modify rows here when rows in Brands or Vehicles change, it would make sense to create a trigger

Comment: You want to `CREATE` the table based on a condition in a `TRIGGER`? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I only want that when I insert a new row don't have any duplicated on this unique selection, this is why I only create the table, it's without any data, I'm trying to study triggers and I thought that if when I insert a new row the trigger could search on the match from brand and veiculo if already exist a correlation, IF exist it should increment the veiculo until reach on a new value, understand?

Comment: @Larnu actually i already create the body of the table, I'm trying to find a way to create a UNIQUE correct match of Brands and Vehicles, this is the idea, I'm studying  triggers, by the way, so I would like to make this trigger that correct my table if any data is put with the same match of brand and vehicles

Comment: That's a different question. Create either a primary key or UNIQUE constraint that covers those columns

Comment: Trigger is definitely the wrong thing here. You just need a key constraint

Comment: You want a trigger to correct the data... how? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably trying to do, by the pattern of the example table, is setting up an auxiliary N to N relationship table.

In this case, by having another table, for `id_veiculo` and its properties, you will be able to have both ids as FKs. As for the primary key in this auxiliary table, it would be both `id_brands` and `id_veiculo`:

```
PRIMARY KEY (id_veiculo, id_brands);
```

Here's another [Stackoverflow question about NxM/NxN relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990459/how-to-create-tables-with-nm-relationship-in-mysql).

Also, it isn't very clear what you're trying to do with the table, but if it's the population/seeding of data, then yes, a Trigger is an viable solution.

Comment: I'm trying to make a way to populate this vehicle table, and I want to have a match with the brand and the vehicle, but each brand needs to have a vehicle 1, 2, 3 ..., N, so I'm trying to create a Trigger that search on the match of Brand and Vehicle if it don't exist accept the insert, if exist it should increment in a loop until the match does not exist than set this value as the new vehicle value creating a new match

Comment: @MiguelRibeiroGodoy Forget words like 'search' and 'loop' in SQL context, try thinking in sets categories (get set of data, update set of data, insert set of data etc). You likely need simple `insert into ... where not exists(...)` type statement in your trigger.